# wordpress show logged in user name before the menu

Tags: wordpress

In wordpress wanted to show username when user is logged in before the menu item.
So I made my code like this

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'show_loggedin_user_name');
function show_loggedin_user_name($items) {
    if(is_user_logged_in()) {
        $user=wp_get_current_user();
    $name=$user->display_name;
    $items .= '<li><a href="">Welcome '.$name.'</a></li>';
  }
    return $items;
}
```

But this one is showing the loggedin user name inside the menu. So how can I show the name before the menu?

Answer (score 0):

The filter you added will put it in the menu. Rather work on a child theme, edit header.php, or sidebar.php, or where ever you want your user name displayed (depends on theme), and add the code to display it there.